# Not able to access Object values returned from a web service in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Here are whats returned in response when hitting the service:

```
 {
   "2019-04-20":{
      "fare":0,
      "IsPricePos":false
   },
   "2019-04-19":{
      "fare":0,
      "IsPricePos":false
   },
   "2019-03-27":{
      "fare":45,
      "IsPricePos":true
   },
   "2019-03-26":{
      "fare":9,
      "IsPricePos":true
   },
   "2019-03-25":{
      "fare":23,
      "IsPricePos":true
   }
}
```

Using the below code for hitting web service and getting a response:

```
  fetch("/somepath/somefurtherpath/" + src + "/" + dst)
              .then(response => response.json())
              .then(result => Object.assign(newObj, result));
```

I am using fetch API as shown.

1) `JSON.stringify(newObj)` returns {}  i.e. empty object string. 
2) Not able to do `JSON.parse(newObj)` as it says its already an object.
3) `Object.keys(newObj)` returns an empty list.

The `console.log(newObj)` gives below (opening the object printed in console):

```
{}
    2019-03-21: 
        IsPricePos: true
        fare: 45
        __proto__: Object
    2019-03-22: {fare: 45, IsPricePos: true}
    2019-03-23: {fare: 45, IsPricePos: true}
    2019-03-24: {fare: 23, IsPricePos: true}
```

I need to access data in JSON and do operations on it. e.g. keys and its values. 
I need to access values of fare or IsPricePos for any given dates as keys.

I tried accessing the values as `newObj."2019-03-25".fare`, but did not work too.

What is the best way to do this? Does React have any specific issue with this type of situation?

I tried hardcoding an object and accessing values using JavaScript, it works well.  But this situation is an issue.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: where is `newObj` defined? Where do you call `JSON.stringify(newObj)`?

Comment: Both inside render() function itself.  newObj is being define just before making the fetch api call.  JSON.stringify(newObj) is just after the fetch api call.

Comment: Please include that code in the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: let newObj = {};

    fetch("/somepath/somefurtherpath/" + src + "/" + dst)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result => Object.assign(newObj, result));

    console.log(JSON.stringify(newObj));

Comment: putting the code in then helped. I got the concept of json response not being avaible synchronously. Thanks a ton @NicholasTower